# Using classification to find the best support and confidence measure in associative rule mining

Tags: data-mining, classification, unsupervised-learning

I have been trying the find the best support and confidence values for associative rules mining. I came across the following approach from an [answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-pick-appropriate-support-confidence-value-when-doing-basket-analysis-with-Apriori-algorithm/answer/Boxun-Zhang) -

> Picking the "appropriate" values for support and confidence can be
>   difficult, as it is very much an unsupervised process.
>
> However, if you transform the output of Apriori algorithm (association
>   rules) into features for a supervised machine learning algorithm, you
>   can examine the effect of having different support and confidences
>   values (while having other features fixed) on the performance of that
>   supervised model (ROC, RMSE, and etc.). Then, the best values for
>   support and confidence are the values that maximize, or minimize, the
>   performance metric.

Being a rookie in this field, I am not sure on how to do this. Could you please help me on this?